# Affirmative action data for college admissions

Tags: data-request, education

Is there data out there on college admissions by race, entry GPA, SAT score, major, and ideally earnings after graduation?

Does such a dataset (or datasets) exist? Any standard format would be useful (csv, xml, accdb, mysql backups, etc).

I know of some summary tables (for example those that are at the end of [The Shape of the River](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691050198)) but I am looking more for more raw data.

Comment: (Statistics based on race are illegal in France.)

Answer (score 3):

The National Center of Education ( nces.ed.gov ), which is part of the US Department of Education, maintains a database of annual survey data from all accredited institutions of higher education. Except for earnings, I have seen all what you referred to:

IPEDS Data Center - http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter/

Since they have a vast number of datasets (CSV tables), I would suggest starting with their Standard Tables to get familiar with their data, and then move to Custom Data Files, where you can select fields to build your own tables.

Comment: Is there a way to select more than one variable with the radio buttons?

Comment: @soandos I'm not a 100% sure what your looking at. If you are at Custom Tables, then first select By Group and expand it and check the box 'All Institutions'. The select By Variables, if you expand the selection you will see checkboxes. You can select multiple checkboxes.